# Can we change tensorflow version on the fly in a python script?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an old python script(tf-1.15.2) that needs to be run in TensorFlow-2.2.0 (can not use tf <2.2), I have migrated most of the code to tf-2.2.0, but there are some tensorflow.contrib related methods that are used in the code. So, I would like to use the old version tf-1.15 for running those lines of code that use tensorflow.contrib related APIs.

So, now the question is I have installed tf-1.15.2 **globally**, I have installed tf-2.2.0 **locally**. But how to access the specific version of the TensorFlow at a specific point in time while the python process is running?

Example code is below

```
import tensorflow as tf             # version: tf-2.2.0 (local package is imported)
isess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
​
# Creatoin of the required placeholders
p = []
for shape in input_shapes:
    p.append(tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape=shape, dtype=input_dtype))
out = tf.einsum(equation, *p)
graph_def = isess.graph_def         
# TODO
# To feed this (graph_def, feed_dict, output_tensors) to a session object of tf-1.15.2 and find the output
```

Now to test the unit test given in [tf_einsum_op_test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6f57007fb8713c2e2cb3f2aa8971544b67cc2516/tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/einsum_op_test.py) in tf_1.15.2 after replacing the einsum with appropriate function (trace/dot_product/...), I would like to revert back to tf-1.15.2 and check the execution.

The underlying need is to find if the tf versions can be interchanged during the execution flow of a python process. Einsum op is considered since it is not directly supported in tf-1.15.2

Answer (score 0):

Up on Experimenting with subprocess API, I found that it is possible to switch between the tf versions during the python process execution through subprocess call.

```
# main.py
import tensorflow as tf             # version: tf-2.2.0 (local package is imported)
import subprocess
import os
isess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
​
# Creatoin of the required placeholders
p = []
for shape in input_shapes:
    p.append(tf.compat.v1.placeholder(shape=shape, dtype=input_dtype))
out = tf.einsum(equation, *p)
graph_def = isess.graph_def
#TODO: Save the graph_def in graph.pb
#TODO: Save the feed_dict in input.npz
#TODO: Save the output_tensors

#Change the python path to the global package
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages'
cmd = ['python3.6','run.py']
out = subprocess.check_output(cmd)         #Subprocess call
```

```
#run.py
import tensorflow as tf            # version: tf-1.15.2 (global package is imported)
import numpy as np
#TODO: Load the graphdef from graph.pb
#TODO: Load the feed_dict from input.npz
#TODO: Load the output tensors
g = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def,name='')
with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    output = sess.run(output_tensors,feed_dict)
```

This works for me.